# How to use .htaccess to redirect non-www pages to www pages with the exception of a single sub-folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all non www. urls leading to my site to www. urls - however, there's one subfolder on my site I don't want changed. The code I've been working with is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Is there a way to tell this piece of code to ignore `domain.com/specialsubfolder`?

Thanks a lot, tried searching for this, but couldn't quite find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way (easy to read and understand) is to add one more condition to ignore this rule if URL starts with `/specialsubfolder` :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/specialsubfolder
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, add such condition into matching pattern (more difficult to read but a tiny bit faster):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!specialsubfolder).* http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**P.S.** You can add `[NC]` flags if case-insensitivity is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that answer was utter perfection.